# Retrieving value from id attribute

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input

I want to list members from a database with two buttons next to each member (delete member and change info). Below is the code so far, but the problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the member id from the input button (placed in the id attribute). How could this be done?

#### This is how I want it to be:

- Name: Steven Larson [delete button] [change info button]
- Name: Julia Segal [delete button] [get more info button]
- And so forth...

**Code so far in MemberView.php:**

```
public function ShowMembers($memberIds) {

    $i = 0;
        foreach ($memberIds as $memberId) {
            $listOfMembers =
            "<b>Name:</b> $fNames[$i] $lNames[$i]
            <input type='submit' id='$memberId' name='delete' value='Delete member' />
            <input type='submit' id='$memberId' name='changeInfo' value='Change info' />
            $i += 1;
        }

    $html = "<form method='post'>
               <p>$listOfMembers</p>;
            </form>";

    return $html;
}

public function TriedToDelete() {
    if (isset($_POST[delete])){
        return $_POST[delete];
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quote on the end of `$listOfMembers`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `foreach( $members as $memberID )` or, the argument should be `function ($membersIDs){}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options to handle the task you're trying to accomplish:

- Convert the buttons to links and use `GET` instead of `POST`. You could make the query-string something like `?action=delete&id=$memberId`.

Try:

```
foreach ($memberIds as $memberId) {
    $listOfMembers = "<b>Name:</b> $fNames[$i] $lNames[$i]
    <a href=\"page.php?action=delete&id=$memberId\">Delete member</a>
    <a href=\"page.php?action=changeInfo&id=$memberId\">Change info</a>";
    $i += 1;
}
```

- Make an individual form for each member and have a hidden `id` field for each one. So, instead of wrapping the full thing with `<form></form>`, wrap each set of buttons instead:

Try:

```
foreach ($memberIds as $memberId) {
    $listOfMembers = "<b>Name:</b> $fNames[$i] $lNames[$i]";
    $listOfMembers .= '<form method="post">';
    $listOfMembers .= '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $memberId . '" />';
    $listOfMembers .= "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete member' />";
    $listOfMembers .= "<input type='submit' name='changeInfo' value='Change info' />";
    $listOfMembers .= '</form>';
    $i += 1;
}
```

- Use JavaScript to set a hidden-field when each individual button is clicked.

Try:

```
<script>
    function submit(button) {
        document.getElementById('id').value = button.getAttribute('id');
        document.getElementById('action').value = button.getAttribute('name');
        button.form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

And each button you would use:

```
$listOfMembers .= "<input type='button' id='$memberId' name='delete' value='Delete member' onclick='submit(this);'  />";
$listOfMembers .= "<input type='button' id='$memberId' name='changeInfo' value='Change info' onclick='submit(this);' />";
```

It's all a matter of opinion really, but I would suggest the 2nd option personally (an individual form for each group) if you have to use POST; otherwise, the 1st (using GET) would be the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='hidden' id='$memberId' name='id' value='$memberId' />       
<input type='submit' id='$memberId1' name='delete' value='Delete member' />  
<input type='submit' id='$memberId2' name='changeInfo' value='Change info' />
```

You should use a hidden field that stores the memberid.

and get the value of the hidden field by using

`$id=$_POST['id'];`

Answer (score 1):

First id should be unique of two elements in html

in your case delete and change button id should be different like

```
public function ShowMembers($members) {

    $i = 0;
        foreach ($memberIds as $memberId) {
            $listOfMembers =
            "Name: $fNames[$i] $lNames[$i]

            
            
            $i += 1;
        }


    return $html;
}
```

form should be different if you are posting via form or else it will set both input fields and by this way you will not know what you actually want to do

now `$POST[$_POST['member_id']."_del"]` will be your del request

and `$POST[$_POST['member_id']."_change"]` will be your change button

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `<a>` tag instead of `<input type="submit">`, so it might look like

```
foreach ($memberIds as $memberId) {
        $listOfMembers =
        "<b>Name:</b> $fNames[$i] $lNames[$i]
        <a href="delete.php?id=$memberId">Delete member</a>
        <a href="edit.php?id=$memberId">Change info</a>
        $i += 1;
    }
```

and you no longer need to use complex form solutions and depend on name of button clicked